# Is it possible to set up a token with a fixed amount available, where all coins can be redistributed among token holders?

Tags: private-blockchain, tokens

I'm new to this so i apologise in advance for my lack of technical knowledge.

What I'm trying to is distribute an investment among people ( a closed group) using tokens, allowing people to buy and sell their stake as they choose.

so basically i want to create a coin with a fixed amount distributed amongst all users. The price of the coin is calculated by putting total coins equal to the portfolio growth €G in real time. When someone wants to invest say €K they buy €K worth of coins. The amount €K would then be added to the €G and the coin value would increase proportionally.

My questions: Would it be possible to have an algorithm that would redistribute all coins proportionally among every coin holder so that they have less coins but their total value remains the same. I know this can be done mathematically quite easily but is their a way to redistribute coins on Ethereum in such a way?

for example

10,000 C coins distributed
G is worth €1,000
so each coin is worth C = 1,000/10,000 = €0.1
Person 1 and 2 have 5,000 C worth €500 each

Person 3 wants to buy 100 worth of coins.
G is now worth €1,100
C = 1,100/10,000 = €0.11
Coins are redistributed in following manner
 1 and 2 have (500/1,100)*10,000 = 4,545.45 C each
 3 has (100/1,100)*10,000 = 909.09 C

The reason I want to keep a limited amount of tokens rather than distribute more is that the value of the coin will be pegged to the growth of the groups' investment and so the increase in coin value will be a direct indicator of the portfolio growth.

If anyone could just tell me whether this is possible or not before I invest too much time on it id appreciate it. And again, sorry for the lack of technical know-how !

Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

As I see it this would only be possible if you create a platform where you handle the accounts of the users that hold the token because if they can take the tokens out of your platform you won't have control over it anymore and you won't be able to change the values of their accounts.

So if you have a platform where you have access to how much tokens each investor has and you can reduce that amount depending on the amount in the portfolio then you'll be able to control the amount of each person.