# Is it possible to set a fixed price for a Token via Smart Contract?

Tags: contract-development, tokens

My Q:
Is it possible to set a fixed amount of ETH for a token via smart contract?

The goal:
I sell a token for lets say 0,001ETH. The owner can resell it, but only for the same amount of ETH. Same for the next one, and so on..

I heard about something like using two smart contracts. Maybe this is the way?

At the moment i am pretty new into smart contracts - any help (or related reading advice) is appreciated.

I saw this nice thingy, but as i understood it is not related:
[Is it possible to set up a token with a fixed amount available, where all coins can be redistributed among token holders?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/33897/is-it-possible-to-set-up-a-token-with-a-fixed-amount-available-where-all-coins)

Thanks :-)

Comment: What's to stop me selling my private key (equating to my token address) to someone in person in the pub for twice the amount? :-)

Comment: Yes, you are right - but thats another story and for my case not relevant. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The idea of decentralization is that people have their token on their wallet, and you do not have control over it.

However there is some exceptions.

Even if you sell a token on a designated market place, anyone could use it elsewhere and sell the token at the prices he wishes on other market places.

Token in a sense is like real world objects. You cannot force someone to sell something for the price you want in the real life. Even a state cannot durably enforce a fixed exchange rate to its sovreign fiat.

However you could design a smart contract, check zeppelin, where your smart contract has the right to sell for the user with the function transferFrom a precise amount of token. Then you could give a fix price to those.

Comment: I am reading through https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/zeppelin-solidity/issues/494 - it looks like there are many awesome functions. Do you know a dev who is into that stuff? I would have some more questions and maybe a job if everything i need is possible.

Comment: Hey I know some Ill send you a message when Im on the computer